# function to show the categories without the subcategories in wordpress with the get_categories() function

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I made this function to show the top navigation for my theme:

```
function costume_menu() {

$categories =  get_categories('hide_empty=0&style=none'); 
  foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $nav = '<li>';
    $nav .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id).'">'.strtoupper($category->cat_name).'</a>';
    $nav .= '</li>';

    echo $nav;
  }

}
```

but it shows all the categories and subcategories together, I tried to read in the codex site of wordpress to exclude only subcategories but I couldnt find anything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
$categories =  get_categories('hide_empty=0&style=none&parent=0');
```

Comment: @IgorIvanovski Nice :) Don't forget to accept answers (on this question, as well as olders ones you've asked).